# How do you keep variables in Visual Studio C sharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, visual-studio-2010

I am creating a web game using *Visual Studio* and *asp.net*.

Now, I want to navigate from form 1 to form 2. However, I dont know how to store the login name and password so that I can update records later from form 2.

This is my code in form 1 where i get the username of the person playing.

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand
     ("select UserName from UserData where UserName = @name", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", TextBox2.Text.ToString()));
            // 2. Call Execute reader to get query results
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            //Label1.Text = "Welcome";
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Label1.Text = "Welcome " + rdr["UserName"].ToString() + 
                                  ". Press the Play Button to Play";
                Button3.Enabled = true;
            }

            if (rdr.HasRows == false)
            {
              //  Button3.Enabled = false;
                Label1.Text = "Sorry You arent in our system. 
                                 Please Register Yourself Before Starting";
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           // Label1.Text = "Error: " + ex.Message + "<br/>";
        }
```

Now, I want to go to form two and update his results. How can I do that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to store the value in session state so that you can retrieve in subsequence page request.

```
// Form 1
while (rdr.Read())            
{                
   Page.Session["UserName"] = rdr["UserName"].ToString(); 
   Label1.Text = "Welcome " + rdr["UserName"].ToString() + ". Press the Play Button to Play";    
   Button3.Enabled = true;            
}

// Form 2        
string username = Page.Session["UserName"].ToString(); // Retrieve in form 2
```

Comment: Thanks. DId that and it works. However in form 2 it say object reference not set to an instance of an object. Do you know how to rectify this?

Comment: Basically, value was not saved in form 1. I updated the code. If error still occurs, pls upload the form 2 code.